# How to interact with telnet using empty

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, expect, telnet

I need to replace a very simple `expect` script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn telnet 192.168.1.175
expect {
    "assword" {send "lamepassword\r"}
}
interact
```

With the equivalent `bash` script using `empty`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
empty -f -i in -o out telnet 192.168.1.175
empty -w -i out -o in "assword" "lamepassword\n"
```

After which I need the user to `interact` with telnet, which I do not know how to do. The closest thing that comes to my mind is binding `stdin` and `stdout` with `named pipes` using something like `socat - in`. Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: my only question is, why are you using telnet?

Comment: Because the host that user interacts with runs telnet.

Comment: I tried `cat out & cat /dev/stdin >in`, it works, but it has an extra newline, tab completion does not work and `ctr+c` terminates `cat` and not the running host process. I am trying to persuade `socat` to act according to those needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `cat out & cat /dev/stdin >in`, it works, but it has an extra
>   newline, tab completion does not work and `ctr+c` terminates `cat` and
>   not the running host process. I am trying to persuade `socat` to act
>   according to those needs.

Using `socat` for transmitting keyboard input to the `telnet` process is a good idea. Example:

```
cat out & socat -u -,raw,echo=0 ./in
```

For allowing `Ctrl`-`C` to terminate `socat`, add `escape=3`:

```
cat out & socat -u -,raw,echo=0,escape=3 ./in
```

But note that this will not terminate the `telnet` session, since it did *start in daemon mode*, so you can reconnect to `telnet` by executing `socat` again. To end `telnet`, you could just `logout`.

Comment: I was looking for the right combination of `socat` arguments, and you suggested ones that provide the EXACT behavior I needed (tab completion, command history, line editing, etc). Thank you. I just replaced `escape=3` with escape=`0x1a` so I can quit with `ctrl+z` and still be able to terminate any host process with usual, `ctrl+c`